# PHP URL format with javascript hash

Tags: javascript, php

Is this URL formating possible using JavaScript without using server .htaccess file

```
index.php#hello.php?a=b&c=d
```

to

```
index.php#hello?a=b&c=d
```

I have load `hello.php` content into `index.php`. It has done done via AJAX and I have shown data of `hello.php` in `index.php` page.

My Question: Is it possible proposed url structure?

Comment: Since it's just a hash that you'll need to handle in your JS anyway, you can make it how ever you want. It's 100% up to your code to work with it. I hope that you have some validation though, so people can't load what ever php-file they want by adding it to the URL.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide some JavaScript tutorial link that can check add extra extension(ex '.php') before querystring. Example: 'hello?a=b&c=d' should be 'hello.php?a=b&c=d'

Comment: Just doing a simple replace should work: `theString = theString.replace('?', '.php?');`

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion